# C# lambda null runtime binding

Tags: c#

I'm running into an odd scenario that doesn't happen on my PC, but does for a coworkers.

I have this piece of code:

```
LoaderHelpers.SetStringValue<blah>(this, "x", $"x response in Header", 
    () => jsonData.x.response[0].value, false);
```

The problem is that sometimes, "jsonData.x" is null and, for my coworker a 'cannot bind to null at runtime exception' is thrown, but not for me there isn't.  I have code to handle the null scenario, but it's like his code never gets to that point and fails at the call level.

jsonData is of type dynamic.

The method code that handles the null scenario:

```
    public static void SetStringValue<T>(IValidate data, string propertyName, 
        string valuePath, Func<string> value, bool required)
    {
        if (data.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value()))
                {
                    if (required)
                        data.DataValidationErrors.Add($"{valuePath} can't be empty");
                    data.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(data, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    data.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(data, value());
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //property doesn't exist
                if (required)
                    data.DataValidationErrors.Add($"{valuePath} doesn't exist");
                data.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(data, null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException($"In {data.GetType()} => SetStringValue.  " + 
                $"Passed property {propertyName}, but property doesn't exist.");
        }
    }
```

Again.  Works perfect for me, but not for him.  I'm completely lost.  Maybe I don't understand how the lamba/function parameters work 100%, but I thought it only got evaluated when value() is invoked.

I should also mention that when I debug this code, I can step into the Nuget package and when he hits the same line, he can't.  This maybe a useful hint.

Comment: FYI, Your exception message says `"{valuePath} can't be empty"` when you're actually validating the `value` argument. In fact, the `valuePath` argument isn't used anywhere (except in that message). Maybe that's what it's for?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong with your code, i can't resist.

First of all, instead of copy/pasting the same stuff over and over, you might want to use a variable:

```
var property = data.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
```

Second, you pass a `Func<string>` and execute it multiple times, why is it even a function then? Yet again, better only evaluate it once and use a variable...

```
var unwrapped = value();
```

That would solve the issue, that [Roberto Vázquez' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55837891/1789202) adresses.

Then you are misusing `NullReferenceException`, instead rather use a `ArgumentException`

Next issue, that `valuePath` is only used in the exception message, that is a poor design to my beliefs.

The generic `T` parameter isnt even used, so get rid of it.

Last but not least, that catch-block doing the exact thing that could possibily throw the exception again, i cant see any reason why you would do this.

Finnaly this whole thing becomes a little more clear but its still a mess.

```
public static void SetStringValue(IValidate data, string propertyName, 
    string valuePath, Func<string> value, bool required)
{
    if(data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));

    var property = data.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    if(property == null)
        throw new ArgumentException($"In {data.GetType()} => SetStringValue.  " + 
            $"Passed property {propertyName}, but property doesn't exist.");


    var unwrapped = value();
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(unwrapped))
        {              
            if (required)
                data.DataValidationErrors.Add($"{valuePath} can't be empty");

            unwrapped = null; // this might be unecessary.

        }

        property.SetValue(data, unwrapped);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // This is probably a bad idea.
        property.SetValue(data, null);

       if (required)
           data.DataValidationErrors.Add(Atleast put a better message here. e.Message ...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If jsonData (or jsonData.x) is null (as it seems to be at this point) it will crash and give you that error every time you call the method value().

You need to check why jsonData.x is null. Maybe it´s a race condition caused by another thread setting this value to null, maybe it´s because a bad jsonData initialization... Can´t say since that code is not here.